# Rotating a label in Visual C++ 6

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-6

I am trying to rotate a label using a function but it is not working.
I only get a label without a rotation.
The label should be rotated along the point (x, y) which is the middle position
of the label (just=TX_JUST_CENTER).
The counter-clockwise rotation angle (=theta) is given as degrees.

I would appreciate any help on this.  Thanks.

```
void do_labely(
    HDC meta_dc,
    SLATE_REC *slate_rec,
    const DEFAULT_STYLE *styl,
    double x,
    double y,
    unsigned char *the_str,
    short just,
    short style_idx,
    short size,
    short stylebits,
    short color,
    short v_just,
    BOOL clip,
    double theta)
{
    LOGFONT lf;
    HFONT font;
    UINT align;

    setup_logfont(meta_dc ,&styl[ style_idx ], size, &lf, slate_rec, stylebits);
    font = CreateFontIndirect( &lf ); 
    GetObject(font, sizeof(lf), &lf);
    SelectObject( meta_dc,font );
    switch (color) {
        case WHITE:
            SetTextColor( meta_dc,RGB( 0xFF,0xFF,0xFF ) );
            break;
        case RED:
            SetTextColor( meta_dc,RGB( 0xFF,0x00,0x00 ) );
            break;
        case GREEN:
            SetTextColor( meta_dc,RGB( 0x00,0xFF,0x00 ) );
            break;
        case BLUE:
            SetTextColor( meta_dc,RGB( 0x00,0x00,0xFF ) );
            break;
        case BLACK:
            // this is the default
            SetTextColor( meta_dc,RGB( 0x00,0x00,0x00 ) );
            break;
    }
    switch (just) {
        case TX_JUST_LEFT:
            // this is the default
            align = TA_LEFT;
            break;
        case TX_JUST_CENTER:
            align = TA_CENTER;
            break;
        case TX_JUST_RIGHT:
            align = TA_RIGHT;
            break;
    }
    switch (v_just) {
        case TX_JUST_TOP:
            // this is the default
            align += TA_TOP;
            break;
        case TX_JUST_BASE:
            align += TA_BASELINE;
            break;
        case TX_JUST_BOTTOM:
            align += TA_BOTTOM;
            break;
    }
    SetTextAlign(meta_dc, align);
    SetGraphicsMode(meta_dc, GM_ADVANCED);

    double rad = theta * PI/180;
    XFORM xform;
    xform.eM11 = cos(rad);
    xform.eM12 = -sin(rad);
    xform.eM21 = sin(rad);
    xform.eM22 = cos(rad);

    //Apply rotation
    ModifyWorldTransform(meta_dc, &xform, MWT_LEFTMULTIPLY);

    //Draw the text
    int x1 = (int)( x * slate_rec->xscale );
    int y1 = (int)( y * slate_rec->yscale);
    TextOut(meta_dc, x1, y1, (char *)the_str, strlen((char *)the_str));

    //Reset the world transform to original
    SetWorldTransform(meta_dc, &xform);

    SelectObject( meta_dc,GetStockObject(SYSTEM_FONT) );
    DeleteObject(font);
}
```

Comment: why do you use VC6 nowadays

Comment: It is an old project and don't have a time to upgrade it.